# Add active class to the selected link in php generated menu

Tags: php, class, dynamic-data

I'm want to add class="active" in list item to highlight the selected menu but I couldn't figure it out how to do this since I'm not really familiar with php.

this is what I have in tpl file

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>
    <a<?php echo $target; ?> href="<?php echo $link; ?>"<?php echo $nofollow; ?>><?php echo $this->escape_html($link_title); ?></a>
    <?php echo $sub_menu; ?>
</li>
```

and in php file

```
        $links = $this->db->GetAll($query);
    foreach($links as $link) {
        $template = $this->PMDR->getNew('Template');
        $template->set('link',$link['url']);
        $template->set('link_title',$link['title']);
        $template->set('nofollow',($link['nofollow'] ? ' rel="'.$link['nofollow'].'"' : ''));
        $template->set('target',($link['target'] ? ' target="'.$link['target'].'"' : ''));
        $template->set('indent',str_repeat('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$level));
        ob_start();
        $this->getMenuLoop($link['id'], $level+1);
        $sub_menu = ob_get_clean();
        if(!empty($sub_menu)) {
            $menu_template = $this->PMDR->getNew('Template',$this->template);
            $menu_template->set('items', $sub_menu);
            $sub_menu = $menu_template->render();
        }
        $template->set('sub_menu', $sub_menu);
        echo $template->render($this->item_template);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tpl, add `$class` (I put it with `$target`, but it can be anywhere inside the `<a>`)

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>
    <a<?php echo $target; echo $class; ?> href="<?php echo $link; ?>"<?php echo $nofollow; ?>><?php echo   $this->escape_html($link_title); ?></a>
    <?php echo $sub_menu; ?>
</li>
```

The in your php file add

```
$current_url = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

AND

```
$template->set('class',(($current_url == $link['url']) ? ' class="active"' : ''));
```

this check to see if the current url is the same as the `$link['url']`, and adds `class="active"

```
    //gets the current page
    $current_url = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $links = $this->db->GetAll($query);
foreach($links as $link) {
    $template = $this->PMDR->getNew('Template');
    $template->set('link',$link['url']);
    $template->set('link_title',$link['title']);
    $template->set('nofollow',($link['nofollow'] ? ' rel="'.$link['nofollow'].'"' : ''));
    $template->set('target',($link['target'] ? ' target="'.$link['target'].'"' : ''));
    $template->set('class',(($current_url == $link['url']) ? ' class="active"' : ''));
    $template->set('indent',str_repeat('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$level));
    ob_start();
    $this->getMenuLoop($link['id'], $level+1);
    $sub_menu = ob_get_clean();
    if(!empty($sub_menu)) {
        $menu_template = $this->PMDR->getNew('Template',$this->template);
        $menu_template->set('items', $sub_menu);
        $sub_menu = $menu_template->render();
    }
    $template->set('sub_menu', $sub_menu);
    echo $template->render($this->item_template);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks! looks like that's should be works! I see the "active" class been added in anchor tag instead in li element
but I guessed it can easily resolve by edit my css..

Comment: You could also put it in the `<li>` by changing it to - `<li <?php echo $class; ?>>`